# find $\lfloor \prod_{n=2}^{2022} \dfrac{2n+2}{2n+1}\rfloor$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> Find $\lfloor \prod_{n=2}^{2022} \dfrac{2n+2}{2n+1}\rfloor$, given that it's coprime to $2022$.

I'm not sure if one can telescope the product somehow. There ought to be a way to simplify the product. It might be useful to replace $2022$ with some arbitrary integer $k\ge 2$. Let $P_k = \prod_{n=2}^k \dfrac{2n+2}{2n+1}$ for $k\ge 2.$ Then $P_2 = \dfrac{6}5,\lfloor P_2\rfloor = 1, P_3 = \dfrac{6\cdot 8}{5\cdot 7}, \lfloor P_3\rfloor = 1.$ Observe that if we let $k!!$ denote the product of all positive odd integers less than or equal to $k$, then $P_k = \dfrac{(2^k k!)/8}{(2k+1)!!/3}$. It seems crucial that $P_{2022}$ only needs to be estimated. So if we can show that it's smaller than a given upper bound, then knowing that it's coprime to $2022$ will tell us that $\lfloor P_{2022}\rfloor = 1.$  Clearly a crude upper bound for $P_k$ is $\prod_{n=2}^k \dfrac{2n+3}{2n+1} = \dfrac{2k+3}{5}$

> For a more precise version of the answer, we have by Stirling's formula that: $n! = \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n e^{\theta_n /(12n)}$ for all $n\ge 1,$ where $0< \theta_n < 1.$ So we have \begin{align*}A_k &= \dfrac{2^{2k+2} (k+1)!^2}{(2k+2)!} = \dfrac{(2^{k+1} \sqrt{2\pi (k+1)} (\dfrac{k+1}e)^{k+1} e^{\theta_{k+1}/(12(k+1))})^2}{\sqrt{2\pi(2k+2)} ((2k+2)/e)^{2k+2} e^{\theta_{2k+2}/(12(2k+2))}}\\
> &= e^{\theta_{k+1}/(6k+6) - \theta_{2k+2}/(24k+24)} \sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{k+1}.\end{align*}

Then for $k=2022,$ we can note that $44.977 < \sqrt{2023} < 44.978$ and $1.77 < \sqrt{\pi} < 1.78$. We then have $78.804 = e^{\ln 0.99} (79.6) < e^{-1/(48552)} (1.77 \cdot 44.977) <A_k < e^{1/(12138)} (1.78 \cdot 44.978) < e^{\ln 1.01} (1.78 \cdot 44.978) <80.9.$ So $29.5 < P_k = \dfrac{3}8 A_k  <30.3,$ and since $\lfloor P_k\rfloor$ is coprime to $2022,$ it must be equal to $29$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$A_k = \frac{8}{3} P_k = \prod_{n=0}^k \frac{2n+2}{2n+1}.$$

The numerator of $A_k$ is $2^{n+1}(n+1)!$.  Multiply top and bottom by this to get

$$A_k = \frac{2^{2k+2}(k+1)!^2}{(2k+2)!}.$$

Stirling's formula approximates this as

$$A_k \approx  \frac{2^{2k+2}\left(\sqrt{2\pi(k+1)}\left(\frac{k+1}{e}\right)^{k+1}\right)^2}{\sqrt{2\pi (2k+2)} \left(\frac{2k+2}{e}\right)^{2k+2}}.$$

Push the power of $2$ inside the square to get

$$A_k \approx \frac{\left(\sqrt{2\pi(k+1)}\left(\frac{2k+2}{e}\right)^{k+1}\right)^2}{\sqrt{2\pi (2k+2)} \left(\frac{2k+2}{e}\right)^{2k+2}}$$

and see that the last factors on top and bottom are identical.  So cancel them to get

$$A_k \approx \frac{2\pi(k+1)}{\sqrt{2\pi(2k+2}}.$$

Plug in $k=2022$ to get $A_k \approx 79.72$, so that $P_k \approx 79.72(3/8) = 29.89.$

Now given that the answer is coprime to $2022$, we know that it can't be $26, 27, 28,$ or $30$.  So I'm going with $29.$  I assume the coprime bit was to help with error control.